# Include stack trace with HttpResponseException

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, asp.net-web-api, stack-trace

I am researching on stacktraces in IIS, so I have created a WebApi project with an endpoint that throws an exception.

If I throw an ordinary Exception:

```
throw new Exception("demo bug - Exception");
```

I get a full stack trace looking like this:

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "demo bug - Exception",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Exception",
    "StackTrace": "   at DemoBug.Controllers.DefaultController.FooBar() in C:\\Workspace\\DemoBug\\DemoBug\\Controllers\\DefaultController.cs:line 24\r\n   at DemoBug.Controllers.DefaultController.Bar() in C:\\Workspace\\DemoBug\\DemoBug\\Controllers\\DefaultController.cs:line 19\r\n   at DemoBug.Controllers.DefaultController.Foo() in C:\\Workspace\\DemoBug\\DemoBug\\Controllers\\DefaultController.cs:line 14\r\n   at DemoBug.Controllers.DefaultController.Get() in C:\\Workspace\\DemoBug\\DemoBug\\Controllers\\DefaultController.cs:line 30\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

If I throw an HttpResponseException however:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "demo bug - HttpResponseException"));
```

Then I get only the `Message` part:

```
{
    "Message": "demo bug - HttpResponseException"
}
```

How can I include the stack trace with HttpResponseException as well?

Comment: Im not sure you can. How about always throwing a 'real' exception and then have an exception filter to format the response how you want?